# regex may or maynot contain a character

Tags: php, regex

I have some regex I am using in PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/D3m57D3m58(.+)D3m59/Uis', $content, $m)
```

This works fine for most of the stuff, but in some examples  `D3m57` and `D3m58` may be separated by a new line, thus no match.

How can I get this to match even if there is a new line in between them, but it still match even if there is not...

i cant alter the string it is matching against

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an optional newline in between them using `?` quantifier, which matches either `0` or `1`:

```
preg_match_all('/D3m57\n?D3m58(.+)D3m59/Uis', $content, $m)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for your help, i am really just learning regex :)